# company-mode clang error

Tags: company-mode, completion, c++, xemacs, clang

I am following [this tutorial](http://tuhdo.github.io/c-ide.html)

When having enabled `company-node` upon typing for instance `std::vec` I get error message in the mini buffer saying:

```
clang failed with error 1:
/usr/bin/clang -fsyntax-only -Xclang -code-completion-macros -x c++ -Xclang -code-completion-at=-:8:14 -
```

However when I type just `vec` and then hit tab, I get a correct completion to `std::vector<Class> var(10, Class());`

Any idea what might be going wrong with clang here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this error recently, too.
I think you could solve it with some clang-flags in the company-clang-arguments user option. You have to specify your Include-Paths and the Library-Paths and link the required libraries. Here it's the standard-library, so you have to edit company-clang-executable from clang to clang++!
But i use Atila Neves' c-make-ide. I can recommend that. You have to write a CMakeLists.txt and specify here the include-paths and libs.
Then call cmake-ide-setup and everything is configured.
I call it via hook.

-tobi

Comment: Where do I find the company-clang-arguments user option?

Comment: First it might be rather company-clang-executable! Change that to clang++. And you find it by M-x apropos, then company-clang and click on edit. Or you can change it in your init-file.

Comment: I tried it and it worked. Let me know if it works at you.

Comment: I changed ` (executable-find "clang)` to ` (executable-find "clang++")` in company-clang.el and that made it work.  Not sure if that is what you meant, but thanks anyway!